# ULTRASONIC SENSOR

Tags: audio, fpga, hc-sr04

I am using the Ultrasonic sensor HC-SR04 for an FPGA project. I am controlling it with an **Atrix 7 Basys 3 board**.
I want to know what is the output coming out of the Ultrasonic Sensor. Is it a time Pulse width? Or is the sensor able to actually give out the distance measure?

[image: This is the Sensor I am using.]

Comment: Please don't shout. Did you get a manual with the sensor?

Comment: Yes, I did. 
I do not know what u mean by don't shout. 
I probably am being an idiot, but I did not understand the manual, that is why I am asking this here.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: [Description and example code](https://opencircuit.shop/blog/de-hc-sr04-ultrasonische-afstands-detectie).

Comment: THIS IS SHOUTING! This is not shouting. You need to edit your question title.

Comment: @JoyadittyaDebnath In English, and probably most other languages that use the Roman alphabet, typing in all capitals is perceived as shouting. It comes across as rude to put your question title in all caps.

Answer (score 0):

The datasheets on these cheap modules are often hard to understand due to the translation from Chinese. They could solve this with a good diagram, but this is often not the case.

Hook it up and run some tests until you understand it. You especially need to understand the boundary conditions, like what happens if there is no echo.

Here is what I found. You send a narrow pulse to the *trig* input and measure the pulse width of the *echo* signal. Here is what you get for an object about 10 inches away.

[image]

From the datasheet:

*Formula: uS / 58 = centimeters or uS / 148 =inch; or: the
range = high level time * velocity (340M/S) / 2*

Comment: The diagram in the link that ocrdu posted is better than the diagram that I had. It clearly indicates *pulse width!*